# How to get first field witout any child value in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xslt-1.0

Do you know how to get only "ADH6170" in xslt 1.0

Thanks.

```
<h2>
    ADH6170
    <strong>
        Bayan kol saati
    </strong>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<xsl:template match="h2">
  <xsl:value-of select="//text()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks lot, it's working perfect now. I'll check after 2 mins.